# Showing a different logo for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

We are looking for a way to show a different logo for a custom post type than to the rest of our site? The custom post type is created with Custom Post Type UI… with ACF and Divi as theme.

We have tried the following:

```
    if ( is_singular('customer') ) { ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/dist/images/logo-customer.png" alt="Logo Customer">
<?php } else { ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/dist/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
}
```

When adding this to functions.php we get an error “syntax error, unexpected end of file”

Not sure what we are doing wrong here but we can't seem to get this code to work

Comment: Where is the original logo code? You usually find this type of conditional in `header.php` rather than `functions.php`, but different themes can set it up however they like. It could be that you need to place this code in a different file to have it run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `<?php` tag before the closing bracket, so it's not being processed. Your code updated below:

```
<?php if ( is_singular('customer') ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/dist/images/logo-customer.png" alt="Logo Customer">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/dist/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Great thanks, that worked perfectly - we tpo place this in header.php instead of funtions.php

Comment: Happy to help, Could you mark this as the accepted answer please? Cheers.